# What does the '#' prefix mean for "ntpq -p"

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I'm adding an NTP server to my npt.conf file and wanted to check if it was successfull using "ntpq -p". In the output I see several prefix, I know that '*' indicates the one being used, '+' indicates those taken into account and '-' those that are ignored. I am however not able to find the meaning of #. This is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that those servers are kept "as backup".  You have `tos maxclock` set to some number in your NTP configuration (possibly 10), and those servers are "extra" pool servers above the maximum number of allowed servers with which to synchronize. They are probably kept as they are still considered good to keep around (note too that there are no `-` sources in your list).

This is [documented here](https://doc.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.6-series/decode/#peer-status-word), which also documents all other possibly symbols that the `ntpq -p` command may show.